# Execute output of cmake target as dependency for another

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── generator
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── include
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── mylib.cpp
```

I would like to build `generator`, then use generator to generate a source file that will be used to build mylib. I tried this:

generator/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(gen main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.cpp
    DEPENDS
        gen
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen -d /tmp
    VERBATIM
)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(py-cppast
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.cpp
        mylib.cpp)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.2)
project(my-project)

add_subdirectory(generator)    
add_subdirectory(src)
```

However, the command is not executed. Instead, I just get the error:

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/....(the cmake binary dir)..../generated.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

How can I tell cmake to execute the program I'm building with it? Is this even possible in a single build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you are generating the file `generated.cpp` in one directory and then trying to add it to a target defined in a different directory. CMake only supports adding generated files to targets defined in the *same* directory scope. The [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) documentation explicitly mentions this restriction.

You probably want to move the generation of `generated.cpp` into the `src` directory. You should also use just the `gen` target name to refer to the executable to run, not `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gen` which is not going to be correct with all CMake generator types. It would also be better style to use the current binary directory rather than the top level binary directory as the output dir. Your `src/CMakeLists.txt` should look something like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated.cpp
    DEPENDS gen
    COMMAND gen -d /tmp
    VERBATIM
)
add_library(py-cppast
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated.cpp
    mylib.cpp
)
```

CMake will automatically substitute the location of the `gen` target for you, even though it was defined in a different directory. There are some further subtleties to be aware of when using generated sources, particularly relating to dependencies. You may find [this article](https://crascit.com/2017/04/18/generated-sources-in-cmake-builds/) helpful to fill in some gaps.